# Installing Ubuntu server 20.04 on Raspberry pi 3B+ broken rendering?

Tags: server, 20.04, raspberrypi

I am trying to install Ubuntu 20.04 on my turtlebot3's Raspberry Pi 3B+.

It is a model from 2017.
I am not sure if it is 64 or 32 bits (I am unable to recognice this information from the hardware, therefore is suppose is 32bits. ).

I followed a classic tutorial with balena etcher and with raspberry pi imager.
1- download ubuntu 20.04 server for ArmHF
2- flash the SD card with balena etcher or raspberry pi image.
3- plug the SD card on the raspberry pi. Boot

Just for ensure I am not missing something obvious I tried this experiment with Balena etcher and Raspberry Imager. I tried this experiment with  ubuntu 20.04 server for ArmHF and Arm64.

In all the cases i have exactly the same problem: [The rendering on booting time seems to be broken](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cMZZT.jpg). I cannot really read anything or understand what is happening.

Finally the boot never finishes, I can only spot the blinking two-characters-in-diagonal cursor, after a large wrongly-rendered text.

Any idea of what can i be missing?

Thanks in avance .

Comment: I am trying right now with Ubuntu Core 18 32bits. The rendering work fine, it even show an ubuntu logo in good quality. I discard some damage on the video processing and on the HDMI port.

Comment: The exact same thing is happening to me on my raspberry pi 3. Ubuntu 20.10, on the other hand works just fine. It seems as though the img for 20.04 provided to us is just broken.

Comment: If you want and advice, i ended up using 18.04. It is only server mode. If you need help making it work with turtlebot3 let me know. It was painful, but i kind of memorized all the commands to make it work :)  (a year ago they were providing a desktop image of ubuntu 16 and i think 18 too. but now the second one disappeared, it is pretty weird the behaviour).